# ajax append multiple times to same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

assuming I have a partial view that is just an editor box for inputting some data (asp.net application)

```
@Html.Editor("New", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "my_editor" } })
```

in my main view, I have a section that I'd like to update with the partial view I mentioned above using an ajax call.

```
<div id="editor_section"></div>
```

My question is, is it possible to continuously append to the same div using the same partial view. In other words, I call ajax once, and a new input box appears. Then I click on the ajax link again, and a second input box appears coming from the same partial view obviously. And I should be able to continue doing this as many times as I like each time appending a new input box under the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but it is not very efficient. You should only have to make the AJAX call once, then you can cache the html you get from the partial view in a JavaScript variable, so when you append it later, you don't have to make the round trip to the server to retrieve HTML you have already requested.

Something like:

```
var inputHtml = null;

var appendInput = function () {
    if (!inputHtml) {
        $.get('/input', function (data) {
            inputHtml = data;
            $('#someDiv').append(inputHtml);
        });
    } else {
        $('#someDiv').append(inputHtml);
    }
};
```

Comment: so retrieve maybe 3 input boxes at a time in case I need them later? and if I need more then call ajax again, otherwise if I don't need anymore then I'm all set? - can you include an example of how to append to the div?

Comment: You only need to retrieve the input via AJAX one time. After that, you already have the HTML so there is no need for further AJAX calls. See my edit. You store the input HTML in a global variable.

Comment: ohhhh ok I understand, I'm trying it now, thank you!

Comment: I definitely will!!! - I have a question, I'm new to jqery/javascript, is the '/input' string pointing to the partial view, or to my controller's ActionMethod?

Comment: also, theres no link appearing when I put the javascript on the page between <script> tags, is there something I'm missing, maybe a Jquery reference? by the way I was using @Ajax.actionlink, is this script equivalent to that?